# Accessing nested property mapped through private field from Linq-to-MongoDB query

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I'm querying a collection using Linq-MongoDB, using the standard C# driver:

```
from n in db.GetCollection<EntityWrapper<Customer>>("Customers").AsQueryable()
where n.Entity.Names.Contains(name)
select n.Entity;
```

This causes an exception however:

```
Class Customer does not have a member called names.
```

As you can see below, I'm wrapping my entities to provide additional metadata without polluting my entities.

```
public class EntityWrapper<TEntity>
{
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity
{
     private List<string> names = new List<string>();
     public IEnumerable<string> Names { get { return names; } }

     public void AddName(string name)
     {
         names.Add(name);
     }
}
```

I've mapped the private field:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Customer>(n =>
{
    n.AutoMap();
    n.MapField("names");
});
```

I've found the data in the database to be correct.

When I remove the private field and change the `Names` property into a `List<string>`, the query runs fine. Obviously, I don't want to go down that route because I'd compromise encapsulation.

Most simple queries work just fine though, e.g.

```
from n in db.GetCollection<EntityWrapper<Customer>>("Customers").AsQueryable()
where n.Entity.Priority > 3
select n.Entity;
```

**UPDATE**

I've figured out a hack that makes the query work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Names
{
    get
    {
        return names;
    }
    private set { } // The LINQ provider expects the property to have a setter
}
```

Still, this isn't close to acceptable.